# Solving differenial equation with multiple function by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I need to solve differential equation given below
`dϑ2/dt= k2*ϑ_1-k3*ϑ_2`
where `k2` and `k1` are constant
I solved the equations but I think Matlab just treating `ϑ_1` as constant     whereas it is also a function of time or (t).
Here is my code

```
syms theta1(t) theta2(t) theta3(t) theta(t);

theta2Sol(t)= dsolve('Dtheta2=k2*theta1-k3*theta2','t');
```

My solution is

`(k2*theta1 - C2*exp(-k3*t))/k3`

My matlab version is 2015b.

Lastly, if I have to assign some value to function is the context right
`1 = theta1(t) + theta2(t) + theta3(t);`

as I tried Matlab help but it is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another equation, e.g. `dϑ1/dt=...` or expressing `ϑ1` in terms of `t` explicitly so that MATLAB can solve the equation. Currently you are providing one equation (`dϑ2/dt= k2*ϑ_1-k3*ϑ_2`) with two unknowns (`ϑ1`,`ϑ2`).
Definitely it can't solve it.

Comment: Actually, by 'solution' means just its integral form. Solution can be obtained when I apply initial conditions.
Problem is theta 1&2 are unknown functions so can't be expressed explicitly in terms of t.
Actually during experiment we have observed some **rate of change** of adsorption (theta in this case) so now we need equation by integrating.

Comment: it is called 'general solution'
@Rody Oldenhuis